# Same URL after VM change on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, virtual-machine

We had a public facing application that was hosted in MS Azure which is currently being switched to new VMs with latest Ubuntu OS.

The new VM has been created and the app has been deployed onto the VM as well.

My doubt is as below.

Assuming we are replacing the existing VM dp-1 with new VM dp-2.

At present the URL, say for example, [www.--.com](http://www.--.com) will be pointing to dp-1

Is it possible to point the current URL to the new VM which is dp-2 without changing any URL?

Comment: Update your DNS records. Since you've provided no details on how your DNS records are managed, that's the most specific advice that can be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to point the current URL to the new VM which is dp-2
> without changing any URL?

Absolutely, you can point the same URL to the new VM.

Same procedure can be followed as (mapping of URL to the old VM) to map the URL to the new VM

Change of URL is not required in this case.

**Note**: If you do not need the mapping of URL to old VM (dp-1), you can remove that mapping.